# memory leak issue regarding contact list in phone book

Tags: android, contactscontract

I am loading the contact list from phone whenever click Tab.
it works fine at first touch, but it leads memory problem from second time.
How should I prevent this issue?

here is the code.

```
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
try {
        contactsCursor= getContentResolver()
        .query(uri, null, null, null,  sortOrder);

        //Log.i("The first one", "" + contactsCursor.getCount());
        if(contactsCursor.getCount()>0){
            if(contactsCursor.moveToFirst()){
                while (contactsCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    String hasPhoneNumber = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                    int contTypeInt=0;
                    String contactType="";
                    ArrayList<String> phoneNumberList= new ArrayList<String>();
                    if (Integer.parseInt(hasPhoneNumber) > 0) {

                        String id = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
                        String phoneNumber = null;
                        if(phones!=null && phones.getCount()>0){
                            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                                int type= phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                                if (type == Phone.TYPE_MOBILE){
                                    phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                    phoneNumberList.add(phoneNumber);
                                }
                            }
                            contTypeInt++;
                            phones.close();
                            phones = null;
                        }
                    }

                    String id = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID+ " = " + id, null, null);
                    ArrayList<String> emailAddressList= new ArrayList<String>();
                    if(emails!=null && emails.getCount()>0){
                        while (emails.moveToNext()) 
                           {
                               // This would allow you get several email addresses
                               String emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                               if(strEmails.equals("")){
                                   strEmails= emailAddress;
                               }else{
                                   strEmails= strEmails+","+emailAddress;
                               }
                               Log.v(name+"==>", emailAddress);
                               if ((!emailAddress.equalsIgnoreCase(""))&&(emailAddress.contains("@"))) 
                               {   
                                Log.d("email", emailAddress);
                                   emailAddressList.add(emailAddress);
                               }
                           }
                        emails.close();
                        emails = null;
                    }

                    if(emailAddressList.size()>0){
                        //primaryEmailList.add(emailAddressList.get(0));
                        contTypeInt++;
                    }
                    if(contTypeInt==0){
                        contactType="";
                    }else if(contTypeInt==2){
                        contactType= "both";
                    }else if(contTypeInt==1){
                        if(emailAddressList.size()>0){
                            contactType="email";
                        }else{
                            contactType="phone";
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(name+" conatctType", contactType);
                    if(name==null){
                        name="";
                    }

                    String []tempArr= name.split(" ");
                    for(int i=0;i<tempArr.length;i++){
                        if(tempArr[i].length()>1){
                            tempArr[i]= tempArr[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + tempArr[i].substring(1);
                        }
                    }
                    String nameTmp="";
                    for(int i=0;i<tempArr.length;i++){
                        if(nameTmp.equals("")){
                            nameTmp= tempArr[i];
                        }else{
                            nameTmp= nameTmp+" "+tempArr[i];
                        }

                    }
                    Constants.contactsList.add(new ContactsData(id, nameTmp, contactType, phoneNumberList, emailAddressList));
                    phoneNumberList = null;
                    emailAddressList = null;
                    tempArr = null;
                }
            }
        }
        contactsCursor.close();
        contactsCursor = null;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Is there anyone to help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this code contained in a Fragment?

Comment: nope. It's in activity

Comment: Okay. How are you implementing tabs and how many of them do you have? I normally use fragments to implement tabs (a fragment for each tab). Unless, by "Tab" do you mean you're clicking a button?

Comment: I don't know why you're focusing on activity or fragment.

Comment: Problem is that the activity that loads contact list gets destroyed due to memory leak issue. I just want to know what causes memory issue and how to overcome it.

Comment: How do you know you have "memory issues"?  What does that mean?

Comment: @wjcoder Because, memory leaks with tabs a lot of times are due to improperly managed Fragments. But, if you don't have fragments, you're probably not using a "Tab." It's probably a button. For anyone to help you fix this problem you're going to have provide more information. "It leads to memory problem second time," doesn't really tell us anything since memory problems can be caused by different things (e.g. an improperly managed bitmap).

Comment: I used tabhost and each tab links to activity.

Comment: while loading the contact list second time, it shows GC_EXPLICIT and GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC in LogCat. It isn't memory issue?

Comment: Okay. That's what I was trying to figure out. A tab host is backed by Fragments. That's why I was asking about Fragments. Hold on, I'll add an answer that should help you out. Can you please post the error that  LogCat is giving you?

Comment: GC_EXPLICIT freed 713K, 54% free 4099K/8903K, external 4957K/6190K, paused 37ms

Comment: GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 113K, 47% free 2940K/5447K, external 1873K/2108K, paused 21ms

Comment: @wjcoder I added an answer that should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html), rather than a cursor.  Content providers were designed specifically to avoid this kind of problem with cursors.

[Here is an example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html).

Basically, you should be querying this data all at once.  You are querying it a bit at a time.  This can cause issues with SQLite and you should probably redesign your code.

Comment: would you please write the code with Content Provider based on my code?

Comment: No, I won't.  "give me the codez" comments aren't appreciated on SO.  Not to mention, there are examples in the link I gave you!  Don't be lazy, put some work in and try to figure it out.  I spent 2 weeks figuring it out myself and learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is probably coming from not checking to see if this Fragment that loads your contacts has already been created. To do this, you need to check to see if the Bundle that is passed to your `onCreate()` method in your Fragment is null. You should only load the contacts if the Fragment is being created for the first time. Example:

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        // load the contacts
    }
}
```

Note that this is important to do in any Fragment since every time the layout changes from portrait to landscape or vice versa, the Fragment will be recreated.

Comment: I didn't use Fragment, used TabActivity

Comment: Okay, well that's mostly likely your problem. The TabActivity class was deprecated in API 13. You should be using Fragments instead.

Comment: I think you're in the wrong way. have you seen the GC_EXPLICIT and GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC error I indicated?

Comment: @wjcoder No, I'm not. Yes. I saw both of those errors. You can't expect a class that was deprecated 6 APIs ago to perform well at all. The reason you're receiving those memory errors is probably because you're using the TabActivity class which was deprecated (which means it should no longer be used). Use Fragments and it should fix your problem.

Comment: I need a solution suitable for current situation as it needs much work to change them as fragments

Comment: Converting it to Fragments would be time well spent.